# Lp norm of a matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-norms

I need a small clarification regarding the $L_2$ norm of a matrix. On [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#L2,1_and_Lp,q_norms), the $L_{p,q}$ norm, for $p=2, q=1$, is defined as:

$$||A||_{2,1}=\sum_{j=1}^n\left(\sum_{i=1}^m|a_{i,j}|^2\right)^{\frac12}$$

Suppose

$$A=\left(\begin{matrix}1&-2\\-3&4\end{matrix}\right)\Rightarrow$$
$$||A||_2=\left(|1|^2+|-3|^2\right)^{\frac12}+\left(|-2|^2+|4|^2\right)^{\frac12}=\\\sqrt{10}+\sqrt{20}\approx7.6344$$

But when I use [Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialReductionsVisitorsBroadcasting.html) with a simple test:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

int main()
{
  Eigen::MatrixXd m(2,2);
  m << 1, -2
      -3,  4;
  std::cout << m.lpNorm<2>() << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

It outputs `5.47223`, which is $\sqrt{30}$, as if the `sqrt()` encompasses the whole sums in the first formula.

My question: what is the correct formula for a generic $L_{p,q}$ norm of a matrix?

Comment: 5.47... is $\|\operatorname{vec}(A)\|_2$ (the "entrywise" $L_2$ norm of $A$).

Comment: @d.k.o. So then which one is correct, `Eigen` or wikipedia? Because that is the output from `Eigen`, with `m.lpNorm<2>()`. Are they wrong? Could you please expand that in a sum, for clarity? I am really confused.

Comment: Nobody is wrong. Eigen's lpnorm<2> function returns the "entrywise" $L_2$ norm. I think u need to read the documentation.

Comment: @d.k.o. Their documentation seems to describe the wikipedia's case, but in the meantime I dug up [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43169781/5309828), which seems to be ok with $\sqrt{30}$. Maybe I am reading the wikipedia wrong, and that overall $\frac12$ power is for all the sum? At any rate, if you wish to write that in an answer, I'll select it.

Comment: Actually, the documentation says that "For matrices, this function does not compute the operator-norm. That is, if *this is a matrix, then its coefficients are interpreted as a 1D vector." This corresponds to the [Wiki section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#%22Entrywise%22_matrix_norms) just above the referenced one.

Comment: @d.k.o. It's finally clearing up, thank you. But, with these now, would you say Frobenius is the choice for balancing a matrix, or should I concoct my own $L_{p,q}$?

Comment: It probably depends on the meaning of "balancing".

Comment: @d.k.o. I was referring to the [arxiv](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.5766.pdf) link in the SO answer (algorithm 3, line 6). Is that Frobenius norm? Also, I meant that about the answer.

Comment: $\|A(:,i)\|_p$ and $\|A(i,:)\|_p$ are the vector norms there ($A(:,i)$ is the $i$-th column of $A$).